# Error for PUT,POST and DELETE RestAPI

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

Only GET method is working all the time but always getting error for PUT,POST and DELETE.
I tried with updating handler mapping thru web.config as well as under IIS Site too.
Initially I was getting error with status code 405 as Method Not Allowed. When I changed Handler mapping as

```
  <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
   <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*."
       verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

<modules>
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

started getting error for 415 as  "Unsupported Media Type".Following is repsonce I am getting

{StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:44:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 100
}}

. Following are my APIcalls

```
    // PUT: api/CreditRequests/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCreditRequest(Guid id, CreditRequest creditRequest)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != creditRequest.CreditRequestId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(creditRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CreditRequestExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/CreditRequests
    [ResponseType(typeof(CreditRequest))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCreditRequest(CreditRequest creditRequest)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.CreditRequests.Add(creditRequest);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (CreditRequestExists(creditRequest.CreditRequestId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = creditRequest.CreditRequestId }, creditRequest);
    }

    // DELETE: api/CreditRequests/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(CreditRequest))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteCreditRequest(Guid id)
    {
        CreditRequest creditRequest = db.CreditRequests.Find(id);
        if (creditRequest == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.CreditRequests.Remove(creditRequest);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(creditRequest);
    }
```

And I am calling them using HttpClient object. with code as

```
  string jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            var content = new StringContent(jsondata, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            using (var client = GetFormattedHttpClient())// Adding basic authentication in HttpClientObject before using it.
            {
              if (IsNew == true)
                    response = client.PostAsync (_webUri, content).Result;
                else if (IsNew == false)
                    response = client.PutAsync(_webUri, content).Result;

            }
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                               return false;
            else
            return true;
```

Comment: Where did you see this usage? `[ResponseType(typeof(void))]`

Comment: I am testing for POST method for first to add record in DB.  and in case on PUT I am focusing to get StatusCode as NoContent

Comment: Remove that attribute.  It is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
protected async Task<String> connect(String URL,WSMethod method,StringContent body)
{
        try
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Variables.SERVERWAITINGTIME)
            };
            if (await controller.getIsInternetAccessAvailable())
            {
                if (Variables.CURRENTUSER != null)
                {
                    var authData = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", Variables.CURRENTUSER.Login, Variables.CURRENTUSER.Mdp, Variables.TOKEN);
                    var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
                }

                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                if (method == WSMethod.PUT)
                    response = await client.PutAsync(URL, body);
                else if (method == WSMethod.POST)
                    response = await client.PostAsync(URL, body);
                else
                    response = await client.GetAsync(URL);

                ....
}
```